# Calling facebook pixel function from pug template

Tags: pug

Trying to include a facebook pixel call within my pug template.  For some reason it's getting stripped out.  Right now I'm trying this:

```
script.
    fbq('track', 'Purchase'); 
    console.log("This is a test");
```

and I get nothing.  Not even the console.log

What should I but doing in order to get this to function as expected?

Comment: What happens when you view source on the rendered page?  Please edit your question and post the complete HTML output from the server.